# flask jinja string to date (strftime) function

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

Hi i am coding flask app but when i send a post data to an html from backend i can't conver it from string to date in html page?

```
@bp.route('/')
def index():
    db = get_db()
    posts = db.execute(
        'SELECT p.id, title, body, created, author_id, username'
        ' FROM post p JOIN user u ON p.author_id = u.id'
        ' ORDER BY created DESC'
    ).fetchall()
    return render_template('blog/index.html', posts=posts)
```

i return posts with "created" date with time and try to display just date

`post['created'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

but i take the error like:
`jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: No filter named 'strfdate'.`

Answer (score 1):

code above has many typos and errors (fixed below) ...

try defining your own custom filter:

```
import dateutil
from dateutil import parser  

@app.template_filter('strftime')
def _filter_datetime(date, fmt=None):
    date = dateutil.parser.parse(date)
    native = date.replace(tzinfo=None)
    if not fmt:
        fmt='%Y-%m-%d'
    return native.strftime(fmt)
```

Inside the jinja template call it as follows:

```
{{post['created']|strftime}}
```

Answer (score 0):

try defining your own custom filter:

```
@app.template_filter('strftime')
def _filter_datetime(date, fmt=None):
    date = dateutil.parser.parse(date)
    native = date.replace(tzinfo=None)
    if not ftm:
        ftm='%Y-%m-%d'
    return native.strftime(ftm)
```

Inside the jinja template call it as follows:

```
{{post['created']|strftime}}
```

Comment: from datetime import datetime

in function:
sent a parameter: data=datatime.now()